# Creating square waves in assembly

Tags: assembly, microprocessors

I'm working on an assignment to generate the fastest square wave on PTT of the Dragon 9S12DT256 board I can using assembly. So far, My code looks like this:

```
DDRT        equ $0242

PTT         equ $0240

            org     $4000

main


            bset    DDRT,#$20   ;set PT5 as output


outerloop

            bset    PTT,#$20    

            ldd #1
loop1   

            nop
            addd    #-1
            bne loop1

            bclr    PTT,#$20

            ldd #1
loop2

            nop
            addd    #-1
            bne loop2

    bra outerloop

    org $fffe
    fdb main
```

From what I've seen (I'm using the TeXas simulator) it looks like it works (It produces what I think is a square wave), but I'm not sure if it's the fastest one I can make. My question is, if this isn't the fastest square wave I can generate, then how would I go about making it faster?

Comment: is that a square wave?  what is the definition of square wave?  the low half is a little longer than the high half, so it isnt a 50% duty cycle.  the nops just slow things down not speed them up right?

Comment: I would expect that "bset PTT,#$20" then "bclr PTT,#$20" would produce a faster wave.

Comment: A square wave can have unequal high:low ratio.